# Which Hibernate dialect can I use if I create JDBC server mock using CitrusFramework

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, mocking, citrus-framework

I need JDBC server mock, then validate request and send proper response.

I build JDBC mock using Citrus. System under test uses these settings:

```yaml
datasource:
  driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  url: jdbc:postgresql://${DHUB_HOST:dell17-test.isb}:${DHUB_PORT:5432}/${DHUB_DATABASE:dhub}?options=-c%20statement_timeout=${datahub.timeout}
  username: ${DB_USERNAME:}
  password: ${DB_PASSWORD:}
      hikari:
        maximum-pool-size: ${JDBC_POOL_SIZE:10}
    jpa:
      properties:
        hibernate:
          proc:
            param_null_passing: true
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
```

I changed settings and set up my Citrus datasourse:

```yaml
driver-class-name: com.consol.citrus.db.driver.JdbcDriver
url: jdbc:citrus:http://localhost:5432/dhub
username: ${DB_USERNAME:sa}
password: ${DB_PASSWORD:}
```

Which dialect should I set up instead of `PostgreSQL10Dialect` to interact between Citrus and my system under test?

Comment: You'll need to find out what SQL dialect Citrus uses (the documentation doesn't seem to tell), and if it uses its own dialect, you may need to write a custom Hibernate dialect for this to work. You may want to consider if using something like testcontainers-java (which allows you to use actual databases) might be more suitable for your tests.